# How to read a sentence with last character as "n"

Tags: c, string

i want to read a full sentence in c language using scanf but when the last character of the sentence is "n" i'am unable to do it!!

i tired using `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s);`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char c,w[50],s[300];
    scanf("%c%s%[^/n]",&c,w,s);
    printf("%c\n%s%s",c,w,s);
}
```

For this input:-

```
z
Learning
C is fun
```

Output is:-

```
z
Learning
C is fu
```

Expected Output:-

```
z
Learning
C is fun
```

Comment: `%[^/n]` reads _up to_ `/` or `n` character. But excluding that character. It will not read the `n` character after. You have to add it yourself. Like with `strcat(..., "n")`.

Comment: "read a full sentence in ... using scanf" is the wrong tool for the job.  It will fail various cases.  Use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `%[^/n]` will cause `scanf` to read input until a `/` or an `n` is encountered.

To read input until a newline is encountered, use `%[^\n]`.